# How to copy and paste styles with Keynote?

Tags: keynote, copy-paste, formatting

I am using `Keynote'09` and have to change a lot of text to specific styles. Since I can't define text styles I have to work around this missing function.
Here is a simple example with a style I would have named **Important** if I could. But I can't.

To use this style on another location I use the `Copy Style` (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) and `Paste Style` (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) of the `Format` menu.

Here is a starting document where `word1` is using the style **Important**:
[image: Before]

I select `word1` and copy its style (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). Then I select `word2` and paste the style just copied
(<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>). `word2` is correctly modified, but the style of the whole line is also changed:
[image: After].
The bullet was eaten!

Since this is something I would like to do about a hundred times on a normal presentation this is a real nightmare.

---

My question is 3 (but they are highly related):

Did I made an error in my use of this function: copy & paste style?

Is this a known bug?

Is this bug fixed in more recent versions of Keynote?

Answer (score 3):

Yes its there Copy design 
Command + Alt (Option) + C (Copy only Styles)
Command + Alt (Option) + V   (Only paste styles) 
Above works absolutely as format painter works in Windows Office.

Comment: I am not interested in Windows Office: this can't be considered as a model of quality software :(.